# Display time in 12-hour format instead of 24-hour format.

Tags: java

please can any one help how to convert hexstring in the format "3676bb6c" in to date and time in the format "1-10-2013 11:47:44"
I tried for this but i am getting 12 hours time format but i need 24 hours format
the code would be  like below

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

 public class HexToDate {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Print.logInfo("REV : " + revHexDate);
     //String revHexDate="369E0Ec7";
    String revHexDate="F52E32F8";
    int decInt = hex2decimal(revHexDate);
    System.out.println("11111 "+decInt);    
    int year = (decInt >> 26);
    System.out.println("year is :"+year);
    int month = (decInt >> 22) & 0x0f;
    System.out.println("month is :"+month);
    int date = (decInt >> 17) & 0x1f;
    System.out.println("date is :"+date);

    int hourOfDay = (decInt >> 12) & 0x1f;
    int hrs=decInt/3600;
    System.out.println("new hrsis "+hrs);
    System.out.println("hourOfDay is :"+hourOfDay);
    int minute = (decInt >> 6) & 0x3f;
    System.out.println("minute is :"+minute);
    int second = (decInt) & 0x3f;
    System.out.println("second is :"+second);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month-1, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);

    //System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat displayFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYY",Locale.US);

    String DDMMYY = displayFormat1.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("DDMMYY is :"+DDMMYY);
    SimpleDateFormat displayFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss",Locale.US);
    String HHMMSS = displayFormat2.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("hhmmss is "+HHMMSS);    


}
public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int d = digits.indexOf(c);
    val = 16*val + d;
    }
    return val;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your hexadecimal string? the number of milliseconds since EPOCH?

Comment: It looks like the number of seconds since epoch to me.

Answer (score 1):

use the following way to for converting hexstring to date

```
Date d=new Date(Long.parseLong("F52E32F8", 16));
System.out.println(d);
```

**output**
Tue Feb 17 20:07:25 IST 1970

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using `hh` instead of `HH` to display hours. [As stated here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the `hh` is used to display a 12-hour format.
Instead of using

```
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss",Locale.US);
```

use

```
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss",Locale.US);
```

Also, you didn't have to create your own method to convert hex to decimal, you could have used, among others

```
long decLong = Long.parseLong("F52E32F8", 16);
```

as *javaBeginner* stated.